# FlexViewer 2.1 - Add scroll for widgetgroup

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer

I have a site that is using the ArcGIS Viewer for Flex version 2.1.  In the header I have a widget group that contains 25 items.  The list is so long that it goes beyond the bottom of the browser window and I can't see the last 5-6 items.  Is it possible to add scroll capability to the widgetgroup so I can scroll through the items?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robert Scheitlin provided an answer over on the ArcGIS Viewer for Flex forum.  Link:

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/36322-FlexViewer-2.1-Add-scroll-for-widgetgroup

His answer:

"Sure just find this block of code and make the changes indicated in red in the HeaderControllerWidget.mxml:"

```
<s:BorderContainer id="widgetList"
                       x="{xOver + 4 - widgetListDG.width/2}" y="{headerContent.height}" width="{widgetListDG.width + 29}" height="300"
                       backgroundColor="{getStyle('contentBackgroundColor')}"
                       borderColor="{getStyle('color')}"
                       borderVisible="true"
                       cornerRadius="3"
                       rollOut="widgetList_rollOutHandler(event)"
                       visible="false">
        <s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
            <HeaderController:WidgetListDataGroup id="widgetListDG"
                                                  width="150"
                                                  dataProvider="{groupWidgetAC}"
                                                  visible="{widgetList.visible}"
                                                  widgetListItemClick="widgetList_widgetItemClickHandler(event)">
                <HeaderController:layout>
                    <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="6"
                                      useVirtualLayout="true"
                                      verticalAlign="middle"/>
                </HeaderController:layout>
            </HeaderController:WidgetListDataGroup>
        </s:Scroller>
    </s:BorderContainer>
```

Since the red doesn't appear here, I needed to add the `<s:Scroller>` parts, and modify the widgetList properties to `width="{widgetListDG.width + 29}" height="300"`.